# Windows Phone Toolkit: Do I really need to install it using NuGet?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, nuget, windows-phone-toolkit

My situation is the following. I'm developing a simple app for my Windows Phone 8 using Silverlight. At some point, I need to add an extra functionality like context menu to my app. It seems, it is enough to add a "normal" reference to the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll  assembly instead of adding the corresponding NuGet reference that installs a lot of stuff in its package I really do not need at all.

So the question is: do I really need to add it as a NuGet package if the functionality provided by the DLL is enough?

I'm asking because I like to keep my projects as clean as it is possible, and I do not like to add unused stuff that eventually makes my projects very big and complex.

Comment: No, you don't need to use NuGet. I'm not sure what more is needed than that. It's up to you and how you want to manage dependencies. For anything critical and open source, I grab not only the DLL, but the source code for the version shipped.

Answer (score 1):

Using Nuget instead of referencing a dll in some folder in your project is the more clean way.

If you add all your references through Nuget, it will provide many benefits, like automatic depedencies resolution and download, upgrades to newer versions, restoring on build and no need to check them into version control system ...

Comment: I do know the benefits of NuGet :). The question is about the specific Windows Phone Toolkit. What if the small part of the functionality I'm using in a particular project works well so there is no need to install the updates automatically, etc. Maybe, it's a question about the WP Toolkit itself and the purpose of every part of it.

Comment: I see no benefit in downloading Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll, placing it in some folder, referencing it, keeping it in source control over using one nuget command to take care of everything